# Dynamically assigning a Regex pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I dynamically Assign a pattern?

I've tried:

```
var str = "hebbbbllo";
var patt = new RegExp;
patt =("b", "g");
console.log(str.match(patt).length);
```

But the code produces an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

I've also tried to use the pattern `"/b/g"` but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
var patt = new RegExp("pattern","flags");
```

So, do this:

```
var str = "hebbbbllo";
var patt = new RegExp("b","g");
console.log(str.match(patt).length);
```

Read more about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

### Update:

If you want to do it in your way, you can do:

```
var str = "hebbbbllo";
var patt = RegExp;
var regex = patt("b", "g");    
console.log(str.match(regex).length);
```

Comment: but i said i want to assign it dynamically, after i'm declaring the variable